# grouping query by 30 min intervals

Tags: grouping

I am trying to get a query to group customer records by 30 min intervals while totaling the number of customers in the 30 min interval and totaling amount of money spent by each customer.

I'm new at this, and I am trying to take it head on.

I am using Microsoft SQL 2005.

Here is an example of what my main table looks like:

```
Cust_ID (Prime key), Date_time (Time of order), Price, and Sales_Tax
```

The intervals should be between `0-29` and `30-59` of each hour for a specific date.

I have figured out how to simply select the records by date range. but I am having trouble with the grouping function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT SUM(price)            AS price_sum,
       SUM(tax)                  AS tax_sum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id)   AS cust_count,
       CONVERT(varchar(13), time_of_order, 120) 
        + CASE 
             WHEN DATEPART(minute, time_of_order) < 30 THEN 'A'
             ELSE 'B'
          END           AS time_chunk_hash
  FROM Sales
       GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(13), time_of_order, 120) 
                    + CASE 
                         WHEN DATEPART(minute, time_of_order) < 30 THEN 'A'
                         ELSE 'B'
                      END
       ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(13), time_of_order, 120)  
                  +  CASE 
                        WHEN DATEPART(minute, time_of_order) < 30 THEN 'A'
                        ELSE 'B'
                     END
```

A working example is at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/794ae/12

The computed `time_chunk_hash` is used to order and group the output, and will look like:

```
 2013-07-28 15A
 2013-07-29 15B
```

which would indicate, for example, the first half hour after 3pm on July 28, and then the second half.

Here's a more readable way of rendering the same query

```
SELECT SUM(price)                  AS price_sum,
       SUM(tax)                    AS tax_sum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id)     AS cust_cnt,
       time_chunk_hash
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT price,
             tax,
             cust_id,
             CONVERT(varchar(13), time_of_order, 120)
              + CASE 
                   WHEN DATEPART(minute, time_of_order) < 30 THEN 'A'
                   ELSE 'B'
               END           AS time_chunk_hash
        FROM Sales
   ) HASHED
     GROUP BY time_chunk_hash
     ORDER BY time_chunk_hash
```

A working example is at:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/794ae/11

Comment: I am getting an error that says, 'MINUTE' is not a recognized built-in function name, will i need to create a minute column in order to correct this error? Also the time of order in my post above is not park of the table. I simply need to replace it with Date_Time correct?

Comment: @user2628624  No need.   Substitute `DatePart(minute, time_of_order)` for `MINUTE(time_of_order)`.    Sorry about that.   The documentation is here:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx .   I've updated my answer to reflect the fix.

Comment: Just to make amends for leading you down the garden path, I've added an SQLFiddle example for you:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/794ae/3

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it is working very well. There is one for thing i would like to ask though. I need to have a total number of customers per interval. So if between 7-28-2013 13:00-13:29 there are 8 customers. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2628624:   I've update both versions of they  query to include a customer count, and have updated the SQLFiddle examples as well.   Note that I've done a distinct count:  this means that if a single customer has placed more than one order in a time slice, he will still only be counted once.

Comment: @user2628624   Hey, would you mind selecting my answer?   I've lost reputation because someone downvoted it...